# Power and automatic differentiation

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm programming a math application where users can define functions and the application evaluates it at a given point. I'm trying to develop the automatic differentiation so I have developed a type with three ordered values (number x vector x matrix) and create the operations as it's defined, so for a given f(x) function (for example f(x)=2*x+2) all c constants have replaced by (c,0,0) and x variables with (x,1,0) so for the function above this gives the form

(2,0,0)*(x,1,0)+(2,0,0)

and the evaluation gives (f,g,h) where f=f(x), g=f'(x) and h=f''(x) (reason for the names is Gradient/Hessian). My problem is what can I do with powers, so for an f(x)^g(x) type of functions? How can I replace the power operation with real exponent for use only '+','-','*','/' operations?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unless you define the logarithm and exponential functions.  Then you can take $f(x)=x^\pi$ to $f(x)=\exp(\pi \log x)$  It seems like your data structure is designed only for polynomials, which may be limiting.  Writing a differentiator for them is not hard, but your users may need a wider range of functions available.  What do you do with the matrix value?

Comment: Works great, but what about x=0? For example f(x)=sin(x^2) then f''(0)=2, but how can i get that?

Comment: @SzántóÁdám:  you would need to implement the chain rule.  $(\sin(x^2))'=\sin'(x^2)(x^2)'=\cos(x^2)(2x)$, which duly is zero for $x=0$

Comment: I've been speaking about the 2nd derivative but it doesn't matter, I have implemented the chain rule but now i want to implement the automatic differentiation and I have to replace every variables to (x,1,0) and contants (c,0,0) and for these types I have only +-*/ implemented (in the chainrule way) so for the input sin(x^2) it has to give the output for x=0: (0,0,2).